# ASP.NET Application Pool process often gets stuck

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis, application-pool

We have a webserver (WinSrv2019) running a few ASP.NET 4.8 websites with a huge traffic.
Each site is running in its personal 64-bit Application Pool (Integrated Pipeline), .NET CLR Version v4.0.

One of the websites gets stuck apparently and stops responding.
Sometimes it continues a few minutes, sometimes it can remain stucked for a hour.

During this period our inter-application logs are empty.
Moreover, IIS log that logs incoming requests is empty as well and incoming requests during this period  aren't being logged.
On the client side browser doesn't get any error, but just continue waiting for response.

Since it happens with the single site only, we've excluded the option that the problem refers server hardware. The server resources usage aren't get over 50%

On the second hand we don't have idea what can cause Application Pool to get stuck in this way.

Please advice.
How we can investigate this issue?
Is there any tool allowing to "debug" what happens inside IIS on the low level?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.leansentry.com/Guide/IIS-AspNet-Hangs

Comment: Take a look at: https://forums.iis.net/t/1159066.aspx?Application+pool+hangs+randomly